# How to save null value to Mysql table DateTime field In C#

Tags: c#, mysql, windows

I want to save null value for dateTime field if the DateEdit (dev express C# windows application control) editvalue is null.

If dateEdit Control has a edit value it save the selected date.If its is null it save a default date But i want to save Null value if the dateEdit value is null.

SAmple COde:
i am using entity frame work,

```
Orders ord= new Orders();
ord.OrderDate= dateEdit1.DateTime;**//here i want to save null value if the dateEdit control value is null** 
Objcontext.Orders.AddObject(ord);
Objcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Need more information ... how are you writing the values to the table?  Post some sample code, please.

Comment: Thank you for replying me, pls tell me how to save null  value to the date field

Comment: The OrderDate property of the Orders class should be nullable -- it should have the type `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>` (this is two different ways of writing the same thing).  I don't know Entity Framework well enough to advise you on how to achieve that.  Once you have achieved that, set the property with the `null` keyword, like this: `ord.OrderDate = null;`

Answer (score 2):

are you using `ADO Command with Parameters`? if so then try *something* this,

```
// other codes here
command.AddWithValue("@paramName",  (dateEdit.EditValue == null) ? DBNull.Value : dateEdit.EditValue);
```

`dateEdit Control` is a DevExpress component right?

or try

```
Orders ord = new Orders();
ord.OrderDate = (dateEdit1.DateTime == null ? DBNull.Value : dateEdit1.DateTime); //here i want to save null value if the dateEdit control value is null 
Objcontext.Orders.AddObject(ord);
Objcontext.SaveChanges();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Field property as NULL for accepting NULL values. Otherwise it will save like "0000-00-00".

Comment: that field has that property .

Answer (score 0):

use Nullable type:

```
DateTime ? nullableDate = GetSomeDate();
```

this also applies to other value types.

There is also DBNull class that may be helpful in such operations. Use could be like this:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("created",nullableDate??DBNull.Value);
```

or similar. starting with .NET Framework 4 MS wants us to pass DBNull.Value for null values.

Comment: i am using entity framework pls tell me how to save null value to date field

Comment: EF will create nullable types for nullable columns if you do everything right

Comment: Thank you aiodintsov Now i saves the null value for the empty dateEdit

Answer (score 0):

**It may help to store null DateTime for your DateEdit.**

```
DateTime? DateEdit = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Orders ord = new Orders();

if(dateEdit1.EditValue!=null)

{ord.OrderDate = dateEdit1.DateTime.Date}

else

{ord.OrderDate= null}

dateEdit control value is null 
Objcontext.Orders.AddObject(ord);
Objcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Now, I am able to save `null` value for empty `DateTime` in the `DateEdit`.